# Should suggested names be written with quotation marks?

Tags: names, quotation-marks

Would a suggested baby name be put in quotation marks before the baby's birth? For example,

> I think you should name your baby "Nathan".

Comment: It would be a bit odd - the quote marks might be interpreted as "scare quotes", implying that there's something weird about the name thus set off. Imagine trying to convey that orthography with "air quotes", and I think you'll agree that if someone wiggled their fingers while *speaking* the suggestion, you'd probably wonder what on earth they were insinuating.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree (as ever). I would use quotation marks, because it is, in a sense, a quotation. One is quoting oneself. Besides, how do you otherwise distinguish what you are saying from "I think, Nathan, you should name your baby". Without quotation marks that, in my view is what the sentence says. Who is Nathan? The baby, or the father doing the naming?

Comment: @WS2: I just looked through several pages of results for [we named the baby](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+named+the+baby%22) in Google Books. That must have included at least a couple of dozen relevant hits with a name immediately after the search string, but only ***one*** of them was in quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the convention is that you place something in quotation marks when you are talking about the name itself, and not about the object of reference of that name.  It has nothing to do with if the baby has been born yet or not.  Compare and contrast the following:

> "Jane" is a pretty name.
>
> Jane is a pretty girl.

Or:

> We want to christen our baby "Nathan."
>
> We want to christen our baby, Nathan.